# Rails - how to place text onto an image within a code loop

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an events site using rails. For my index page I have a code loop showing an image, the event title and the date for each event. I need to show the title and date ON TOP OF the image. The code blocks for the title and date are wrapped in h2 and h3 tags respectively. I'm not entirely sure how to style this properly.

My html page is set out as follows -

index.html.erb - events

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="events">    
            <% @events.each do |event| %>
                <li><%= link_to (image_tag event.image.url), event, id: "image" %></li>
            <div id="text"> 
                <h2><%= link_to event.title, event %></h2>
                <h3><%= link_to event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y'), event %></h3>
            <% end %>
            </div>  
        </div>          

      </div>
   </div>   
 </div>
```

My CSS for the image section is as follows -

Events.css.scss

```
div.container {
width: 100%;

}   



.col-md-12 { 

     width: 100%;


}    

 div.events img {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 25px;


}

 div.events li {

    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

What do I need to do to place the text elements of this code loop onto the relevant image?

Comment: A couple of hmtl fixes: change the `.events` `<div>` to a `<ul>` and make sure `</li>` comes right before `<% end %>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to pack your stuff into one DOM element. If you are unsure you can create a quick static HTML prototype (plain old html file) and then put the corresponding elements into your rails views. Here is a quick example, take care you set li positioned relative and the div absolute so you can position it the way you need it...

```
    <ul>
      <li class="teaser">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
          <div class="event-details">
            <h2>foo</h2>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="teaser">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
        <div class="event-details">
          <h2>foo</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    li.teaser { width: 400px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
    li.teaser img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    div.event-details { background: white; padding: 25px; position: absolute; bottom: 25px; right: 25px; }
```

In your case for sure... `<% @events.each do |event| %><li>...</li><% end -%>`

Comment: That's worked - thank you. If I want to change the position of the text do I just adjust the bottom & right positions?

Comment: There's top, right, bottom and left at your service.